# Lightbox isn't working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently trying to implement lightbox onto my website, but I cannot get it to work, I don't think there is anything conflicting with it, and I have placed all of the files in the correct locations and linked them how it tells you to on the lightbox 2 website. (http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/)

Just to double check:

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

is in the head tags,

```
<script src="js/lightbox.js"></script>
```

Is at the bottom of the page, just before the closing body tag.

lightbox.css is in the css directory
   lightbox.js is in the js directory

```
<li><img src="images/1.png" data-lightbox="image-1" /></li>
```

and above is what all of my image tags look like.

I'm unsure why it isn't working. I have the files uploaded to a server, and it doesn't work on there either.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Put lightbox.css above jquery, just in case, also... Did you check console for errors?

Comment: Any chance we can get a link to your site?

Comment: Any errors in your [JavaScript console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation says to use `<a>` (anchor tag) to trigger the lightbox.

```
<li>
  <a href="images/1.png" data-lightbox="image-1">
    <img src="images/1.png" />
  </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using an `img` tag, and they explicity say to use an anchor `a` one.

For me, it's working like a charm:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightbox2/2.8.1/js/lightbox.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightbox2/2.8.1/css/lightbox.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/d7/24/f9/d724f9e2e1a300dbdcb11b1d0491c884.jpg" data-lightbox="panda">Cute baby panda</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/25/17/52/2517525a674d91b127938e55a72f0f12.jpg" data-lightbox="panda">Another</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/qfsRZsvraD8/hqdefault.jpg" data-lightbox="panda">Last one</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```